# How can I fix 'continue not properly in loop' error in my Python while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, continue

I'm trying to make it so that my program will write the input again if the answer isn't within 5 to 10 but when I try to use while True and continue it says that the continue is not properly in loop. It only fixes when I take away the space infront of the line but that creates an "syntax error" on the "else:" line.
I cannot move the "continue" forward one space or more or backwards any spaces either. same for the "while True" line.

```
import random
number = random.randint(5,10)
name1 = input("What is your name? ")
while True:
    guess2 = int(input("Pick a number between 5 and 10\n"))

if guess2 <5 or guess2 >10:
    print("this isn't a number between 5 and 10 please try again.") 
    continue

else:
    print("\nYour guess was", guess2)
    print("the computer guessed", number)

if guess2 != number:
    print(name1 + " you have lost try again")
else:
    print(name1 + " you have Won the game try again if you want to")
print("\nNAME:",name1,"\nUSER GUESS:",guess2,"\nCOMPUTER CHOICE:",number,"\nGAME OVER")
```

I have tried looking up an explanation but to no avail since they don't work either.

Comment: You probably meant the lines containing the `continue` statement to be part of the loop, but for that they would have to be indented more.

Comment: The `input()` statement is the **only** line of code that is indented underneath the `while` loop.  The `continue` statement is NOT part of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue is a [statement for flow control](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), used to continue the iteration over the next value. In this case, it's used in a for loop.

```
for number in range(10):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(f'Number {number} is pair')
        continue
    print(f'Number {number} is not pair')
```

In this case, everytime you find a pair number it will continue and not print the second statement. Inside functions where you need to return something and then the iteration stops, it's pretty usefull.

```
def find_the_first_odd_number(sequence_long: int):
    for number in range(sequence_long):
        if number % 2 == 0:
            continue
        else:
            return number
first_odd = find_the_first_odd_number(10)
print(first_odd)
```

If you don't have a for loop and you want to not do anything, the propper statement is "pass" to continue the flow or break, to stop the process.